# I can't add transition to the hover effect

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm working with React and Tailwindcss. I have a card, a shadowed text on top of an image. Shadowed text has hover effect so it doesn't appear unless hovered. I wanted to make hover effect more smooth so I tried giving it transition but I just couldn't. Where exactly should I give transition class?

Here's my code:

```
<div className="group relative grid w-80 h-full flex-col items-end justify-center overflow-hidden rounded-4xl text-center">
              <div className="absolute h-full w-full overflow-hidden bg-cardBg bg-cover bg-center">
                <div className="hidden group-hover:block cursor-pointer w-full h-full to-bg-black-10 bg-gradient-to-t from-black/70 via-black/20"></div>
              </div>

              <div className="hidden group-hover:block cursor-pointer relative p-6 px-6">
                <h2 className="mb-6 block text-4xl font-medium leading-[1.5] tracking-normal text-white antialiased">
                  Shadowed Text Bla Bla Bla
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I'm expecting a smooth effect on the hover.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitions cannot happen to between changes in `display` values. To have a fade, you could consider applying `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none` and `opacity: 1` instead of `display: block` by replacing `hidden` and `group-hover:block` with `opacity-0` and `group-hover:opacity-100`. You'd also need to apply some sort of `transition` property, such as by using the `transition` class:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        cardBg: 'url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000)',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="h-80">
  <div class="group relative grid w-80 h-full flex-col items-end justify-center overflow-hidden rounded-4xl text-center">
    <div class="absolute h-full w-full overflow-hidden bg-cardBg bg-cover bg-center">
      <div class="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 cursor-pointer w-full h-full to-bg-black-10 bg-gradient-to-t from-black/70 via-black/20 transition"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 cursor-pointer relative p-6 px-6 transition">
      <h2 class="mb-6 block text-4xl font-medium leading-[1.5] tracking-normal text-white antialiased">
        Shadowed Text Bla Bla Bla
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```